# How to make source code hidden or encrypted while inspecting a site?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to web development. I'm creating a website. I have to call some webservices inorder to access some db contents.

```
 $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://some_url',
    headers : {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept' : 'application/json'
                },
   data : JSON.stringify(data)
        }).then(
            function(response) {
                    $scope.myData = response.data;
                              }
```

The above code is written inside the jsp file. but when we inspect the page we can see the url and with the url anyone can access data using postman. I have to avoid that. Some please give any suggestion to improve the security.

Comment: You cannot hide that sort of information from curious users of your front-end client. The url will always be accessible to the client.

Comment: Front-end is always accessible for anyone. Nothing you can do about that :)

Comment: You take it the wrong way. Read this http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/ , and especially section "Step 4: Securing API keys". If you need secured transactions, you must have your own back-end. Then from your back-end, you can access third-party API with sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

You secure the database. Anything sent to the client is available for them to see. You can uglify & minify...but the code is still there.

Comment: I cant do anything from the server side. I have to make it securer from the front end,.

Comment: There is no way to hide or encrypt your client side code. You should never have any confidential information there.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very, very broad...

The standard way these days is having all database calls made inside a [RESTful webservice](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm). The front-end (usually HTML+JavaScript) will make [REST requests](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijqy.html) to it.

Then, if you need to secure one (or all) requests, provide an authentication method. The most common is using [JWT tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token).

Comment: Thank you. I will refer these things.